# Authentication for Angular4 project using expresshs and mysql

Tags: mysql, express, session, cookies, jwt

Im implementing a system using angular4 which need authentication method with 'remember me' option in it. ExpressJS and mysql are used to middle-ware and database connection respectively. I have read about cookies, sessions and JWT. But I don't know which one is preferred and how to use them. Can someone help me please.

This is the **server.js** file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
// const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
// const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const connection = require('../db.connection');
// app.use(cookieParser());
// app.use(session({secret: "Shh, its a secret!"}));

const UserRoute = require('./routes/user');

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is up on 3000");
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('express server working....');
});

app.post('/log_in', (req, res) => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query("select * from user  where username=? and password=aes_encrypt(?,?)",
      [req.body.username, req.body.password, req.body.key],
      (err, res) => {
        if(err){
          reject(err);
        }else if(res.length) {
          resolve({reply: 'login success'});
        }else {
          resolve({reply: 'no such user found'});
        }
      });
  }).then((result) => {
    res.status(200).send(result);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  });
});

app.post('/sign_up', (req, res) => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query("insert into user values(?, aes_encrypt(?,?))",
      [req.body.username, req.body.password, req.body.key],
      (err, res) => {
        if(err){
          reject(err);
        }
        resolve({reply: 'login success'});
      });
  }).then((result) => {
    res.status(200).send(result);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  });
});
```

Assume that the user table only has two columns(username and password).
Which technology is prefered in this scenario and how to use it in Angular app and in Express middli-ware?? And please tell me, if above methods to sign_in and sign_up are inefficient.

Thank you......